# rotate animation render only half of the element

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a rotating gold ray of lights, below image is the achieved layout using html and css but when I tried to add a rotate animation, seems layout cut on half. Below code snippet is what is my attempt. Any help, ideas is greatly appreciated.

[image]

```css
@import('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
body {
    background: #ededed;
    padding: 64px 0;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px
}

.banner {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}

.winners-intro {
    background: #ededed;
    z-index: 999
}

.winners-intro,
.winners-intro .winners-light {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

.winners-intro .winners-light {
    -webkit-animation-name: winners_light;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: winners_light;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .radial-light {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: gold;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 100px 50px gold;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 100px 50px gold;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 100px 50px gold;
    -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 100px 50px gold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light {
    position: absolute;
    background: gold;
    height: 200vh;
    width: 20px;
    opacity: .5;
    background: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(2) {
    transform: skewX(30deg)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(2),
.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(3) {
    background: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(3) {
    transform: skewX(60deg)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(4) {
    transform: skewX(90deg)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(4),
.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(6) {
    background: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(6) {
    transform: skewX(-30deg)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(7) {
    transform: skewX(-60deg);
    background: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 27%, gold 50%, transparent 73%, transparent 90%, transparent)
}

.winners-intro .winners-light .light:nth-child(8) {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: 10px!important;
    background: transparent;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 10%, gold 50%, transparent 90%, transparent);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 10%, gold 50%, transparent 90%, transparent)
}

.winners-intro .winners-trophy {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10
}

@-webkit-keyframes winners_light {
    to {
        transform: rotate(-1turn)
    }
}

@keyframes clouds {
    to {
        transform: rotate(-1turn)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="winners-intro">
  <div>
   <div class="winners-light">
    
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="light"></div>
    <div class="radial-light"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify the code like below where you will not have the issue:

```css
body {
  background: #ededed;
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100vh;
}

.light {
  height: 100vmax;
  width:100vmax;
  background: 
      radial-gradient(circle ,rgba(255, 215, 0, 1 ) 8vmax,transparent 8vmax),
      radial-gradient(circle ,rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6)8vmax,transparent 17vmax),
      
      linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 10%,gold,transparent 90%) center/10px 100%,
      linear-gradient(to right , transparent 10%,gold,transparent 90%) center/100% 10px;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   animation:move 5s linear infinite;
}
.light:before,
.light:after{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   background:inherit;
   background-size:0 0,0 0,10px 100%,100% 10px;
   transform:rotate(30deg);
}

.light:after{
   transform:rotate(-30deg);
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    transform:rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="light"></div>
```